# PHP checkdnsrr() function not giving expect results

Tags: php, function

I was trying out checkdnsrr() function in PHP to test whether a given hostname is valid or not.

Below is the PHP code:

```
$url = "this_is_a_wrong_url.com";
if (checkdnsrr($url, 'A')) 
{
    echo "Domain exists.";
}
else
{
     echo "Domain doesnot exists.";
}
```

But it is returning true even for invalid url's.

What am I doing wrong? I am using PHP 5.3.5

EDIT: **This code is working fine on Linux machines with same PHP version. Its giving invalid result only on Windows machine.**

Comment: I tested your code and it seems to work fine for me. (running PHP 5.3.3). Maybe its something outside of PHP causing this?

Comment: @Chief17 yes you are right. I tested it on one other system(running 5.3.6) and it is working as expected. Any tips on how to debug what is causing this not to work properly on current system?

Comment: At the command line, try `ping`ing / `nslookup`ing the domain names and see what you get?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some ISPs will redirect invalid domains to their own search servers. TimeWarner/RoadRunner is one such ISP. Your code works fine, but you might want to check to make sure they don't resolve to your ISP's search servers. Use gethostbyname first to check an invalid domain, then use that to check against.

```
if (checkdnsrr($url, 'A') && gethostbyname($url) != '204.232.137.207' && gethostbyname($url) !='66.152.109.110')
```

Or better is

```
if(checkdnsrr($url,'A') && !in_array(gethostbyname($url),gethostbynamel('this_is_a_wrong_url.com')))
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @aynber for the answer. It helps me a lot. But I think it was not complete for me. I have modified a little bit your answer for checking the email domain is valid or not. Actually, it was not working for .co,.co.in,.in domains. So, I extend your answer a little bit :)

```
$email = trim($_GET['email']);

// take a given email address and split it into the username and domain.
list($userName, $mailDomain) = split("@", $email);
$tld = explode('.', $mailDomain,2)[1];//for php>=5.4.0
if(checkdnsrr($mailDomain,'A') && !in_array(gethostbyname($mailDomain),gethostbynamel('this_is_a_wrong_url_xx_xx_xx.' . $tld))) {  
echo "Domain exists.";  
} else { 
echo "Domain not exists.";  
}
```

@aynber, +1 for the answer:).

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 $url = "this_is_a_wrong_url.com";
    if(checkdnsrr(($url),"A"))
{
    echo "Domain exists.";
}
else
{
     echo "Domain doesnot exists.";
}
```

so the `$url` in brakets

Comment: I think he meant `if(checkdnsrr(($url),"A")`. I cant see any reason it would make the script work though. No offence @aurel :)

Comment: @RepWhoringPeeHaa yes :) is that what he wanted

Comment: @aurel k, but I still fail to see what that does :P

Comment: @RepWhoringPeeHaa checks if the url is registered. so if  you use google.com, it would state true. To be hones I never used it I just saw that his code was missing the brakets

Comment: @aurel I meant the extra braces

Answer (score -2):

I found here:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdnsrr.php

Changelog

Version     Description

5.3.0   This function is now available on Windows platforms.

5.2.4   TXT type was added.

5.0.0   AAAA type was added.

It mean you cannot call this function under php < 5.3 on windows

Comment: OP said the used version is 5.3.5